# How to replace ^ character in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a json data in my hand and I want to clear this character "^"

but I can't get out of it because it's a regex operator.

The code I wrote:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data)
data = data.replace(/^1/g, '');
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` has a special meaning in RegEx, you have to escape `\^` to match that literally

```js
let data = 'test^^^^test^'
data = data.replace(/\^/g, '');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: not works i tried, thx